# bibtex cannot find database entry

Tags: bibtex, windows

After reading [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/134621/bibtex-didnt-find-a-database-entry) and [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33416/bibtex-i-didnt-find-a-database-entry-for) question I'm still unable to get bibtex to find an article reference:

```
C:\Users\CV\> bibtex cv
This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (MiKTeX 2.9)
The top-level auxiliary file: cv.aux
The style file: biblatex.bst
Database file #1: cv-blx.bib
Database file #2: publications.bib
Warning--I didn't find a database entry for "bibl:sebi_01"
Biblatex version: 3.0
(There was 1 warning)
```

The file containing the publications is:

**publications.bib**

```
@Article{sebi_01,
  Title                    = {Title},
  Author                   = {A. author1, B. author2},
  Year                     = {2015}
}
```

Why can't bibtex find the reference (key) **sebi_01**?

The **.tex** file where I'm citing the article is:

**cv.tex**:

```
\printbibliography[type=article,prefixnumbers={A-},resetnumbers=true,title=Publications]
\nocite{bibl:sebi_01}
```

**Edit #1:**

After modifying both the **.tex** and **.bib** file now there appears to be a problem with the authors in the **.bib** file.

```
C:\Users\CV>bibtex cv
This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (MiKTeX 2.9)
The top-level auxiliary file: cv.aux
The style file: biblatex.bst
Database file #1: cv-blx.bib
Database file #2: publications.bib
Biblatex version: 3.0
Too many commas in name 1 of "A. author1, B. author2" for en
try sebi_01
while executing---line 2513 of file biblatex.bst
Too many commas in name 1 of "A. author1, B. author2" for en
try sebi_01
```

**Edit #2:**

I've ran latex from the command line and the following error is shown:

```
! LaTeX Error: File `my_picture' not found.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...

l.62 \makecvtitle

?
```

Strangely, when building in texworks the **.pdf** file is created with the respective picture inside. This only happens when running **latex.exe** from the command line. The picture is in the same directory as the **.tex** file.

Comment: The error says that you've cited `bibl:sebi_01`, not `sebi_01`.

Comment: I've updated the question with the file where I'm citing the reference.

Comment: Ye, but that shows exactly what I've said: you've cited `bibl:sebi_01` but in your database that's not present: you have `sebi_01`.

Comment: I've modified the .tex file and now a different problem related to the authors came up.

Comment: Did you run LaTeX, BibTeX, LaTeX?

Comment: Note that there's a separate error in the `sebi_01` entry (which, by the way, is flagged by biblatex): `{A. author1, B. author2}` is not correct; you should write `{A. author1 and B. author2}`.

Comment: @JosephWrtight I've updated the question. [at]Mico thanks for the suggestion. I've updated the .bib file

Comment: Is there a reason why you don't run `pdflatex` (instead of `latex`) from the command line? (TeXworks invokes `pdflatex`, not `latex`).

Comment: I've called pdflatex and now the document builds

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is based on not using the same label for reference  in the tex file and the bibtex file. It is likely it would help others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting answer from comments. The citation key `bibl:sebi_01` had to be set to `sebi_01` and `pdflatex` invoked instead of latex in the order:

```
pdflatex cv
bibtex cv
pdflatex cv
```